# How to know whether the gsutil command which is executed successfully or got error by means of response status or error code?

Tags: gsutil

Currently I am using gsutil rsync command to move files from GCS to AWS . I have got a lot of file in GCS to be moved to AWS. How do I know that all the files are copied without any error,or if any error occurred how do I know that something went wrong. Is there any way to get the response status or response error codes ?

Answer (score 0):

see the documentation
https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/rsync#options

`-C option:`

> If an error occurs, continue to attempt to copy the remaining files. If errors occurred, gsutil's exit status will be non-zero even if this flag is set. **This option is implicitly set when running** **"gsutil -m rsync..."**. Note: -C only applies to the actual copying operation. If an error occurs while iterating over the files in the local directory (e.g., invalid Unicode file name) gsutil will print an error message and abort.

It means that `rsync -m` won't stop on error, but the error code will be non zero.
Hope it helps.